# Method was too large error during PowerMockito

Tags: java, aws-lambda, jvm, mockito, powermockito

This AWS lambda function java code compiled without any issue. But when execute the unit testing using powerMockito, error starts appearing when we add the Main class to the @PrepareForTest
There are multiple methods getting called  from parent methods.
I tried mocking few methods using PowerMockito. But still getting method size exceed exception.

**Java Code**

```
Public class ClassA implements RequestHandler<InputPayLoadPojo, Response> {

        Public Response handleRequest(InputPayLoadPojo, Context) {
                Private ReturnType ChildMethod1()     {
               …..     
               }
                Private ReturnType ChildMethod2 ()    {
                       Private ReturnType SubChildMethod2 (){
                       ……..
                       }
               …..     
               }

                Public ReturnType ChildMethod1 ()     {
               …..     
               }

               .
               .
               .
               .

               Private ReturnType ChildMethod18 ()   {
               …..     
               }


        }

}
```

**Test class**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.net.ssl.*" , "javax.management.*"})
@PrepareForTest({ ClassA.class})
public class SynchronousTest {

        ClassA obj = PowerMockito.spy(new ClassA());
@Test
public void testSynchronousTranslation() {

        doReturn(somevalue).when(obj, “ChildMethod1”, anyObject….);
        doReturn(somevalue).when(obj, “ChildMethod2”, anyObject….);
        doReturn(somevalue).when(obj, “ChildMethod3”, anyObject….);

        obj.handleRequest(someInputPayLoadPojoObject, someContextObject);

}

}
```

**Getting error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Method was too large and after instrumentation exceeded JVM limit. PowerMock modified the method to allow JVM to load the class. You can use PowerMock API to suppress or mock this method behaviour.
        at com.taas.amazonservices.lambda.TaaSSyncLambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(TaaSSyncLambdaFunctionHandler.java)
        at taas.amazonservices.lambda.SynchronousTest.testSynchronousTranslation(SynchronousTest.java:165)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:326)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Comment: Your method was too complex, after instrumentation, it's bytecodesize exceeded ~64kB

Comment: If I mock all methods except one which I want to test, will this resolved this issue. I trying to mock all the methods and check whether this is resolved.

Comment: Also I failed to understand why this is appearing when calling in unit testing. But during java compilation, this issue is not appearing.